# How do i copy n characters for m lines in a file (in c)?

Tags: c

I have a file of 1000 lines with up to 70 characters in them. I want to copy the 13 first in a table, the 15th-30th in another table... i tried many different things without success, here's one of them :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define size_num 13  // 13 character with \0 included
#define line 1000
#define carac 300 // like 300 characters per line

int verifFile(FILE*pf)    //check file
{
    if (pf == NULL)
    {
        printf("can't open file");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    float td,tf;
    td=clock(); //count execution time of program
    FILE* pf=NULL;
    pf = fopen("call.txt", "r");
    verifFile(pf);
    char str[line];
    char number[line][size_num];
    while(fgets(str,line,pf)!= NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", str);
        number[line][size_num]=str[line]; // here i want number to copy the 13 first characters
                                            //of each 1000 lines
    }
    printf("\nsecond : \n"); // separates the printings
    for(int i;i<1001;i++)
    {
        for(int j;j<14;j++)
        {
            printf("%c",number[i][j]); //supposed to print each charac stored (doesnt work)
        }
    }
    tf=clock();
    printf("\n execution time : %f secondes",(tf-td)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);   //display execution time
    return 0;
}
```

there are no warnings so i dont know what to do :/

Comment: Not entirely clear What about the 14th?

Comment: numero or number? :-)

Comment: Side note: If `verifFile(pf)` returns 1, you should abort and not continue.

Comment: At least these problems: `i` and `j` are uninitialized. `for(int i;.` -> `for(int i=0;...`. Possibly more prolems elsewhere.

Comment: in the file each line is like : "+XXXXXXXXXXX FirstName Name incoming/outgoing"
so i want to store the +XXXXXXXXXXX of each line in a table same for FirstName, Name and i/o
sorry for not making it clear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I initialized `i` and `j` to 0 and when trying to print the table output is 100s of line of "êFC└¨⌂   PFK└¨⌂" so i think the problem is with `number[line][size_num]=str[line];`

Comment: _" I initialized i and j to 0..._": maybe you did that somwhere somehow, but not in the code you show here. `for(int i; ... ` here `i` is declared, but not initialized to any values.

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry i meant i did it right after your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you copy the substrings is broken:

```c
    while(fgets(str,line,pf)!= NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", str);
        number[line][size_num]=str[line]; // here i want number to copy the 13 first characters
                                            //of each 1000 lines
    }
```

First of all, you always assign to `number[1000][13]` which is illegal as `number` only has 1000 rows, i.e. maximum index is `999`. Also each row only has 13 elements making 12 the maximum index.

Same out of bounds access happens for `str`.

Then you do not have any counter indicating in which element of your array you want to copy the string.

Finally, strings cannot be copied by a simple assignment. You need to use `strcpy` or `strncpy`.

This loop should look like that:

```c
    int row = 0;
    while(fgets(str,line,pf)!= NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", str);
        strncpy(number[row], &str[0], size_num);
        number[row][size_num-1] = 0; // Don't forget to terminate the string!

        // Add copying the other parts here as well...

        row++;
    }
```

Then you also have a problem with printing the content:

```c
    for(int i;i<1001;i++)
    {
        for(int j;j<14;j++)
        {
            printf("%c",numero[i][j]); //supposed to print each charac stored (doesnt work)
        }
    }
```

Again, you have out of bounds accesses.
And you print all possible lines even if the file only contains a few lines.
Also you do not even initialize your loop counters to 0.

Do this instead:

```c
    for(int i = 0; i<row;i++)
    {
#if 0
// use this part if you really want to print char by char...
        for(int j = 0; j<size_num; j++)
        {
            printf("%c",numero[i][j]); //supposed to print each charac stored (doesnt work)
        }
#else
// Use this if you want to print the string at once.
        printf("%s\n",numero[i]);
#endif
    }
```

Comment: thank you for helping me ! I tried what you said : `#define size_num 14` and `#define ligne 999` and the codes your wrote, the output when printing is a counting from 6407008 to 6420994 adding 14 between each line. I used `printf("\n%d",&row);` and it came out as : 6422024
I don't really know what to do with that sorry

Comment: I had a typo in my `printf` command. Updated format specifier. Sorry. But why would you print `row`? That is only the number of lines.

Comment: i printed `row` to see its value, with it being the number of lines it should be 1000 right ? Because it gives 6422024 so i dont know, maybe it is the amount of character in the file ?

Comment: If you have exactly 1000 lines, then yes. You still seem to print the address instead of the value.

Comment: i corrected in my code and it works thank you very much for helping me !
I will try to do the same with the other parts of the file hope it'll go well